# Uploadify pass formdata variable to handler.ashx

Tags: c#, .net, handler, uploadify

I am trying to send parameters from my .aspx page into my handler.ashx with the help of "formdata" in uploadify using .net and c# when I upload a file. The parameters are take from textboxes that have values in the.
The code is:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").uploadify({
             'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
             'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
             'auto': true,
             'multi': true,
             'buttonText': 'Select File(s)',
             'removeCompleted' : false,
             'fileTypeDesc' : 'PDF Files',
    'fileTypeExts' : '*.pdf',
    'formData' : { "id": "<%=TBcustnom.Text %>", "pwd": "<%=Pwd.Text %>" }


         });
     });
```

handler.ashx only receives the first value (id), but not whats in the pwd part.

```
string id = context.Request["id"]; 
string pwd = context.Request["pwd"];
```

How do I configure the javascript to send both parameters? or how do I configure the handler.ashx to receive the pwd as well?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I needed to do was to look at the right place.

```
string id = context.Request["id"]; 
string pwd = context.Request["pwd"];
```

this is supposed to be

```
string id = context.Request.Form[1]; 
string pwd = context.Request.Form[2];
```

Take care!

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {};
data.id = <%TBcustnom.Text %>;
data.pwd = <%Pwd.Text %>;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID %>").uploadify({
        'swf': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader': 'Handler.ashx',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': true,
        'buttonText': 'Select File(s)',
        'removeCompleted': false,
        'fileTypeDesc': 'PDF Files',
        'fileTypeExts': '*.pdf',
        'formData': obj: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
});
```

In the server side,

```
var jsonString = context.Request["obj"];
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonObjects = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. My code can at least send what's inside the id-parameter. But I don't understand why it can't send what is inside the Pwd-parameter

Comment: Actually it's ok, I found out how I could get the data in the handler. I just had to "open up the context" like string custno = context.Request.Form[1];
string pwd= context.Request.Form[2];
The code above was correct except this part.
Thanks for trying!