# Unable to get a control value in ashx

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I am using uploadify to upload a file. By following this tutorial:

[TUTORIAL](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Select-and-Upload-Multiple-Files-Gmail-Style-using-JQuery-and-ASP.Net.aspx)

Problem is that although I am able to get file on ASHX using

```
HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
```

I am unable to get value of a input box on the same form:

```
string str = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Name"];
```

**ASPX form**

```
  <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server"  >
            <a href="javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart()">Start Upload</a>&nbsp; 
           |&nbsp;<a href="javascript:$('#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clear</a> 
            <div style = "padding:40px">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

            </div>
            <asp:TextBox MaxLength="100" CssClass="txtbox" Width="300px" ID="txtImgRemark" runat="server"> </asp:TextBox>
           <input type="Text" name="password" id="password" value="0" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(window).load(
    function() {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'formData': { 'Name': 'arbaaz', 'Num': 1 },
        'multi': true,
        'auto': false
    });
   }
);
</script>
```

**ASHX**

```
  public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
            string str = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["password"];
            string savepath = "";
             //blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another parameter **formData** in the fileUpoad() function during the call like below.

```
$(window).load(
    function() {
        $("#<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>").fileUpload({
        'uploader': 'scripts/uploader.swf',
        'formData': {'someKey' : 'someValue', 'someOtherKey' : 1},
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': false
    });
   }
);
```

On server side

```
string value= context.Request["someKey"];
```

For more Details you can check this link:[formData](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/)

Comment: And how do I access this value in ashx? by HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["someKey"]  ? its still null

Comment: please check this link http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/customizing-the-server-side-upload-script/

Comment: the link you mentioned explains it in php

Comment: can you please update your code of handler with question so i can check the issue.

Comment: `context.Request["Name"];` gives null as well

Comment: please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043672/uploadify-pass-formdata-variable-to-handler-ashx

Comment: In your script your are passing  'formData': { 'Name': 'arbaaz', 'Num': 1 }, name and num you should replace one of them with password. so you can get it in request.

Comment: I have did while debugging. I just forgot to replace it while posting it. I have changed it now in my post.

Comment: I should atleast get Num with `context.Request["Name"];` right? But I am getting null.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem where context.Request["Name"] gave null. This was because the HTTP post request contained a querystring AND form-data. It can't have both.